# Pandas combinations and merge

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

If you have the following dataset,

```
BookStrategy    Trade   DV01    Maturity

STRAT1  Bond    1000    04/05/23

STRAT1  Swap    -200    04/05/23

STRAT1  Swap    -300    04/05/23

STRAT1  Swap    -500    04/05/23
```

And the ultimate aim is to get this

```
STRAT1  Bond    1000    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -200    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -300    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -500    04/05/23

STRAT1  Swap    -200    04/05/23    STRAT1  Bond    1000    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -300    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -500    04/05/23

STRAT1  Swap    -300    04/05/23    STRAT1  Bond    1000    04/05/23
STRAT1  Swap    -200    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -500    04/05/23

STRAT1  Swap    -500    04/05/23    STRAT1  Bond    1000    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -200    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -300    04/05/23
```

In short, if I have

row1

row2

row3

row4,

I want the combinations to be

```
row1 --> row1 row2 row3 row4

row2 --> row2 row1 row3 row4

row3 --> row3 row1 row2 row4

row4 --> row4 row1 row2 row3
```

The code that I have so far is this,

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('bla.csv')

print (dataset.head(1))

df = dataset.values

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.reshape(1,-1))
```

This gives the output,

```
0   STRAT1  Bond    1000    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -200    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -300    04/05/23    STRAT1  Swap    -500    04/05/23
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want. Are you trying to expand each column to have 4 columns? How are you obtaining the last 8 columns in your `ultimate  aim`?

Comment: what is the logic behind this ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to expand it to contain all the possible rows.
So if I had 10 rows with 3 columns each, I would have 10*3 columns in each row (3 columns for itself and the other 27 columns for the 9 other rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `pop` for moving the list

```
l=[]
for x in range(len(df)):
    s = df.apply(tuple, 1).values.tolist()
    s=[s.pop(x)]+s
    l.append(s)

pd.DataFrame(l).stack().apply(pd.Series).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)

Out[398]: 
        0     1     2         3       0     1     2         3       0     1  \
        0     0     0         0       1     1     1         1       2     2   
0  STRAT1  Bond  1000  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap  -200  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap   
1  STRAT1  Swap  -200  04/05/23  STRAT1  Bond  1000  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap   
2  STRAT1  Swap  -300  04/05/23  STRAT1  Bond  1000  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap   
3  STRAT1  Swap  -500  04/05/23  STRAT1  Bond  1000  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap   
     2         3       0     1    2         3  
     2         2       3     3    3         3  
0 -300  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap -500  04/05/23  
1 -300  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap -500  04/05/23  
2 -200  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap -500  04/05/23  
3 -200  04/05/23  STRAT1  Swap -300  04/05/23
```